# Spring JPA to query using "IN" in select statement

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to query the table based on two status for example status1 or status2. How should I achieve in one SQL statement using Spring JPA.

```
ws = consultSessionRepository.findByShareIdAndStatus(consultId,
                    consultStatus.active);

public interface ConsultSessionRepository extends JpaRepository<consultSession, Long>  {

    @Query("select ws from consultSession ws where consultId = ?")
    consultSession findByconsultid(String consultId);

    @Query("select ws from consultSession ws where shareId = ?")
    List<consultSession> findByShareId(String shareId);

    consultSession findByShareIdAndStatus(String shareId, consultStatus satus);

}
```

Trying to achieve something like below

```
select * from consultSession where status in ('ACTIVE', 'ACTIVE1') and shareid = '<share id>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can construct the query using a method name, which follows the rules mentioned in the documentation below, like this:

```
consultSession findByShareIdAndStatusIn(String shareId, consultStatus... states);
```

or using `@Query` annotation, which is IMHO more readable:

```
@Query("FROM consultSession cs WHERE shareId = ?1 AND status IN (?2)")
List<Foo> find(String shareId, consultStatus... states);
```

Btw, I assume this `consultId in ('ACTIVE', 'ACTIVE1')` is a typo and it should be `status` instead of the `consultId`.

---

### References

- [Spring Data JPA Docs: Query construction using method names](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation)

Comment: Do I need to send the parameter as list? ArrayList<WhiteboardStatus> status = new ArrayList<WhiteboardStatus>();
   status.add(WhiteboardStatus.active);
   status.add(WhiteboardStatus.vcactive);
   ws = wsRepository.findByShareIdAndStatus(whiteboardId, status);

Comment: got it, trying with ws = wsRepository.findByShareIdAndStatus(wdId,status1,status2)

Comment: @user1595858 You can change the method signature to take a list, or any collection, array or varargs (which are used in my example and in your last comment). All of those options should work according to the docs.

Comment: i'm trying the one you suggested and it fails with below error. org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Encountered array-valued parameter binding, but was expecting [backend.model.consultStatus]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Encountered array-valued parameter binding, but was expecting [backend.model.consultStatus]

Comment: @user1595858 Your query method name probably ends with `AndStatus`, however it should be `AndStatusIn`.